# HTML5 catch a image drop-down event while dragging in canvas using kinetic-v4.0.0.js

Tags: html, canvas, drop-down-menu, drag-and-drop

I'm trying cancel event dragging, but it does not work.I use the kinetic-v4.0.0.js library.Does someone have a good idea?